# SQL Server Stored Procedure for Fruit Checks with several joins - timing out

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Stored procedure timing out because of being too slow, it could be because it's using `outer full join`

**Error**:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The
>   timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the
>   server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
>   (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection

Based on my research I think increasing time out may fix the error problem but then I want to decrease the time it takes to execute too, any improvement would be welcomed. I will post table structure if needed but that going to be a lot. Also I am not sure if increase time out is the best solution

```
/* Stored procedure to get fruits checks that the user has access to*/
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Fruits_GetChecksForUser]
(
    @UserID VARCHAR(200),
    @CheckUrlFilter varchar(256)
)
AS

SELECT Distinct
    Fruits_Checks.*,
    ManagementCommittees.Title As CommitteeName,
    FruitCategories.ID As CategoryID,
    FruitCategories.Title As CategoryName,
    dbo.IsUserInGroup(@UserID, FruitCategories.FruitOfficerGroupID) AS IsUserFruitOfficer,
    dbo.IsUserInGroup(@UserID, Fruits_Checks.AllocatedGroup) AS IsUserCheckResponsible,
    Policies.CompanyID,
    Policies.ID As PolicyID

FROM Groups_UserAccess
INNER JOIN FruitCategories_GroupAccess ON FruitCategories_GroupAccess.GroupID = Groups_UserAccess.GroupID
INNER JOIN FruitCategories ON FruitCategories.ID = FruitCategories_GroupAccess.FruitCategoryID
INNER JOIN Policies ON Policies.ID = FruitCategories.PolicyID
LEFT JOIN Policies_AppSettings ON Policies_AppSettings.PolicyID = Policies.ID
LEFT JOIN Clients_AppSettings ON Clients_AppSettings.ID = Policies.CompanyID
FULL OUTER JOIN Fruits ON Fruits.CategoryID = FruitCategories.ID
INNER JOIN Fruits_Checks ON Fruits_Checks.FruitID = Fruits.ID
INNER JOIN ManagementCommittees on Fruits_Checks.CommitteeID = ManagementCommittees.ID

WHERE 
    Fruits.ID IS NOT NULL 
    AND Fruits_Checks.URL LIKE '%' + @CheckUrlFilter + '%' 

ORDER BY Fruits_Checks.EndDate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase of time is surely not a solution. It looks like innecessary/avoidable full outer join, distinct instruction and possibly inline function calls (would be fine to have a look into them too) slow donw your query drammaticaly. 
At least an execution plan is required to provide you with more detailed answer.

Comment: i changed the execution plan and it seemed to help me, thanks :), once i am happy with testing, i will upvote you too